# On counting pairs of words that differ by one letter

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> Let us consider n words, each of length k. Those words consist of letters over an alphabet (whose cardinality is n) with defined order. The task is to derive an O(nk) algorithm to count the number of pairs of words that differ by one position (no matter which one exactly, as long as it's only a single position).
>
> For instance, in the following set of words (n = 5, k = 4):
>
> abcd, abdd, adcb, adcd, aecd
>
> there are 5 such pairs: (abcd, abdd), (abcd, adcd), (abcd, aecd), (adcb, adcd), (adcd, aecd).

So far I've managed to find an algorithm that solves a slightly easier problem: counting the number of pairs of words that differ by one GIVEN position (i-th). In order to do this I swap the letter at the ith position with the last letter within each word, perform a Radix sort (ignoring the last position in each word - formerly the ith position), linearly detect words whose letters at the first 1 to k-1 positions are the same, eventually count the number of occurrences of each letter at the last (originally ith) position within each set of duplicates and calculate the desired pairs (the last part is simple).

However, the algorithm above doesn't seem to be applicable to the main problem (under the O(nk) constraint) - at least not without some modifications. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: For each word, can you add each possibility of that word minus one letter?  Then if there is a collision, that means you have detected a pair?  Eg from abcd add abc, abd, bcd, then for abdd add abd, -- notice a pair -- etc?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming n and k isn't too large so that this will fit into memory:

Have a set with the first letter removed, one with the second letter removed, one with the third letter removed, etc. Technically this has to be a map from strings to counts.

Run through the list, simply add the current element to each of the maps (obviously by removing the applicable letter first) (if it already exists, add the count to totalPairs and increment it by one).

Then totalPairs is the desired value.

**EDIT:**

**Complexity:**

This should be `O(n.k.logn)`.

You can use a map that uses hashing (e.g. `HashMap` in Java), instead of a sorted map for a theoretical complexity of `O(nk)` (though I've generally found a hash map to be slower than a sorted tree-based map).

**Improvement:**

A small alteration on this is to have a map of the first 2 letters removed to 2 maps, one with first letter removed and one with second letter removed, and have the same for the 3rd and 4th letters, and so on.

Then put these into maps with 4 letters removed and those into maps with 8 letters removed and so on, up to half the letters removed.

The complexity of this is:

- You do 2 lookups into 2 sorted sets containing maximum k elements (for each half).
- For each of these you do 2 lookups into 2 sorted sets again (for each quarter).
- So the number of lookups is 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + k/2 + k, which I believe is `O(k)`.
- I may be wrong here, but, worst case, the number of elements in any given map is `n`, but this will cause all other maps to only have 1 element, so still `O(logn)`, but for each `n` (not each `n.k`).

So I think that's `O(n.(logn + k))`.

.

**EDIT 2:**

**Example of my maps (without the improvement):**

`(x-1)` means `x` maps to `1`.

Let's say we have `abcd, abdd, adcb, adcd, aecd`.

The first map would be `(bcd-1), (bdd-1), (dcb-1), (dcd-1), (ecd-1)`.

The second map would be `(acd-3), (add-1), (acb-1)` (for 4th and 5th, value already existed, so increment).

The third map : `(abd-2), (adb-1), (add-1), (aed-1)` (2nd already existed).

The fourth map : `(abc-1), (abd-1), (adc-2), (aec-1)` (4th already existed).

`totalPairs = 0`

For second map - `acd`, for the 4th, we add 1, for the 5th we add 2.

`totalPairs = 3`

For third map - `abd`, for the 2th, we add 1.

`totalPairs = 4`

For fourth map - `adc`, for the 4th, we add 1.

`totalPairs = 5`.

**Partial example of improved maps:**

Same input as above.

Map of first 2 letters removed to maps of 1st and 2nd letter removed:

```
(cd-{  {(bcd-1)}, {(acd-1)}  }),
(dd-{  {(bdd-1)}, {(add-1)}  }),
(cb-{  {(dcb-1)}, {(acb-1)}  }),
(cd-{  {(dcd-1)}, {(acd-1)}  }),
(cd-{  {(ecd-1)}, {(acd-1)}  })
```

The above is a map consisting of an element `cd` mapped to 2 maps, one containing one element `(bcd-1)` and the other containing `(acd-1)`.

But for the 4th and 5th `cd` already existed, so, rather than generating the above, it will be added to that map instead, as follows:

```
(cd-{  {(bcd-1, dcd-1, ecd-1)}, {(acd-3)}  }),
(dd-{  {(bdd-1)}, {(add-1)}  }),
(cb-{  {(dcb-1)}, {(acb-1)}  })
```

Comment: A little remark regarding the first part of your answer: I think you count pairs of identical words in the _totalPairs_ variable. (The _ith_ letter mustn't be just removed, it's essential to determine whether two words identical at the other positions are in fact different or not). Possibly you used a mental shortcut that I didn't notice. :)
Anyway, the approach seems sound. I have given this problem some thought after posting it here and I am about to provide a slightly different (and almost complete) solution as a separate answer (too long to fit in here).

Comment: @Quintofron I added examples which may provide some more insight into my thoughts.

Comment: I understand the point of the first approach; my concern regarded the case when some words are duplicated. Let's assume you are given three words: axb, ayb, axb. What result will your algorithm provide (5)? As for the improved maps, I will give it a thought later :)

Comment: @Quintofron I see, duplication would be a problem. Preprocessing it to remove (+ count) duplicates might be the way to go (with some changes to the algorithm). Using a O(kn) sorting algorithm (such as [Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) wouldn't increase the overall complexity. An alternative is storing the removed letter in the above structure, but I think this could add complexity.

Comment: What if I have 12 characters long word? What's the improved mapping? The problem is there https://csacademy.com/ieeextreme-practice/task/coupon-codes/submissions/

Answer (score 1):

It's been two months since I submitted the problem here. I have discussed it with my peers in the meantime and would like to share the outcome.

The main idea is similar to the one presented by Dukeling. For each word A and for each ith position within that word we are going to consider a tuple: (prefix, suffix, letter at the ith position), i.e. (A[1..i-1], A[i+1..n], A[i]). If i is either 1 or n, then the applicable substring is considered empty (these are simple boundary cases).

Having these tuples in hand, we should be able to apply the reasoning I provided in my first post to count the number of pairs of different words. All we have to do is sort the tuples by the prefix and suffix values (separately for each i) - then, words with letters equal at all but ith position will be adjacent to each other.

Here though is the technical part I am lacking. So as to make the sorting procedure (RadixSort appears to be the way to go) meet the O(nk) constraint, we might want to assign labels to our prefixes and suffixes (we only need n labels for each i). I am not quite sure how to go about the labelling stuff. (Sure, we might do some hashing instead, but I am pretty confident the former solution is viable).

While this is not an entirely complete solution, I believe it casts some light on the possible way to tackle this problem and that is why I posted it here. If anyone comes up with an idea of how to do the labelling part, I will implement it in this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can put each word into an array.Pop out elements from that array one by one.Then compare the resulting arrays.Finally you add back the popped element to get back the original arrays.
The popped elements from both the arrays must not be same.
Count number of cases where this occurs and finally divide it by 2 to get the exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you would enumerate the language - you would likely use a recursive algorithm. Recursive algorithms map onto tree structures. If you construct such a tree, each divergence represents a difference of one letter, and each leaf will represent a word in the language.

Answer (score 0):

How's the following Python solution?

```
import string

def one_apart(words, word):
    res = set()
    for i, _ in enumerate(word):
        for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
            w = word[:i] + c + word[i+1:]
            if w != word and w in words:
                res.add(w)
    return res


pairs = set()
for w in words:
  for other in one_apart(words, w):
    pairs.add(frozenset((w, other)))

for pair in pairs:
  print(pair)
```

Output:

```
frozenset({'abcd', 'adcd'})
frozenset({'aecd', 'adcd'})
frozenset({'adcb', 'adcd'})
frozenset({'abcd', 'aecd'})
frozenset({'abcd', 'abdd'})
```